# Java Changing table headers after getting data from DB Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using Netbeans, SWING to get data from mysql table to jTable. I done it, but headers of table. Headers are the same like in mysql table. How to change headers of jTable after getting data from DB?

P.S.

Default headers don't works in this issue.

This is auto-generated code:

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// 
private void initComponents() {
    bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

```
progressjournalPUEntityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("progressjournalPU").createEntityManager();
pupilsQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : progressjournalPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pupils p");
pupilsList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : pupilsQuery.getResultList();
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle("Журнал успеваемости");
setResizable(false);

jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {

    },
    new String [] {
        "#", "ФИО", "Курс", "Предмет", "Оценка"
    }
) {
    Class[] types = new Class [] {
        java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
    };

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types [columnIndex];
    }
});

org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, pupilsList, jTable1);
org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${pupilMark}"));
columnBinding.setColumnName("Pupil Mark");
columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${pupilSubject}"));
columnBinding.setColumnName("Pupil Subject");
columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${pupilCourse}"));
columnBinding.setColumnName("Pupil Course");
columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${pupilName}"));
columnBinding.setColumnName("Pupil Name");
columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${pupilId}"));
columnBinding.setColumnName("Pupil Id");
columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
jTableBinding.bind();
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(15, 15, 15)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 616, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addContainerGap())
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addContainerGap()
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);

bindingGroup.bind();

pack();
```

}//

And this code is locked for editing.

Comment: *"Headers are the same like in mysql table."*  If you want them different, map them to those different values and use the different values for the table header.  This seems like 'not a real question' to me.

Comment: Unless the question is: how can I change the header used by a `JTable` . I will post an answer for that before hitting the close button

Comment: But in what part of code I neeed to change columns and how?

Answer (score 1):

Call `getMetaData()` on your sql `ResultSet`. The [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) contains the column names. The column header names are (like the row data) read from the `TableModel`.

Answer (score 1):

The headers of your table are determined by the [`TableModel#getColumnName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnName%28int%29), as is clearly stated in the javadoc of that method:

> Returns the name of the column at columnIndex. This is used to initialize the table's column header name